# How to add custom class to td in slot items?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How to add class with condition to td ?

```
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td>
          {{ props.item.id }}
        </td>
        <td :class="{'users-table__item--delete': props.item.login === 'admin'}">
          {{ props.item.login }}
        </td>
        <td :class="{'users-table__item--delete': props.item.login === 'admin'}">
          {{ props.item.type }}
        </td>
      </template>
```

It does not work.

Upd.

My version: "vuetify": "^2.1.15",

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-text class="pa-0">
      <template v-if="usersList.length">
        <v-data-table
        >
          <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
            <td>
              {{ props.item.id }}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{ props.item.login }}
            </td>
          </template>
          <template slot="item.action" slot-scope="props">
            <div class="d-flex">
              <v-btn
                @click="changeUser(props.item.id)"
              >Edit</v-btn>
            </div>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
      </template>
      <p v-else>No users</p>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

I have item.action slot for show buttons. May be this affects on it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you forgot to add **tr** tag.

This code works:

```
<template v-slot:item="props">
  <tr>
    <td :class="{'green': props.item.id > 4 && props.item.id <= 5,'red': props.item.id > 10}">{{ props.item.id }}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: ```          <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
            <tr class="notactive">
              <td class="test">
                {{ props.item.id }}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{ props.item.login }}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{ props.item.type }}
              </td>
            </tr>
          </template>```

Comment: I can't add class to td or tr.

Comment: which basic component do you use? v-data-table, or something else?